# Does the demon slayer sword have any advantage over the demon dweller sword?

Tags: black-clover

The first 2 swords Asta have are the demon slayer sword and the demon dweller sword. As far as I understand the demon dweller sword can nullify spells like the first sword, and it glows and it seems like it can fire some energy at long range when he makes a slash. How about the first sword? Does the first sword have any advantage over the second sword?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the abililties of demon dweller sword:

• Anti magic

• Magic Absorption

• Ability to store magic from allies and fire it.

• Shoot anti magic slashes ( in the manga ).

And here are the abililties of demon slayer sword:

• Anti Magic

• Magic Deflection

• Ability to transform into black divider

• Ability to fly by manipulating anti magic flow ( in the manga ).

So, advantages are that it can deflect magic, reach a new destructive form, and can be used instead of a broom.

Hope this helps.